# Move jquery resizable handles out of the divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, handles

I have 3 divs. One inside the other.

**jQuery**

```
    $(function() {
        $("#div1").resizable({
            handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"
        });
        $("#div1").draggable();
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" style="left: 2px; top: 2px; z-index: 2; width: 100px; height: 70px; background-color: black">
    <div id="div2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: green; position: absolute;">
        <div id="div3" style="width: 90px; height: 60px; position: relative; top: 50%; margin: -30px auto auto; border: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-resizable-handle { width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #000000; }
.ui-resizable-n { top: 1px; left: 50%; }
.ui-resizable-e { right: 1px; top: 50%; }
.ui-resizable-s { bottom: 1px; left: 50%; }
.ui-resizable-w { left: 1px; top: 50%; }
.ui-resizable-nw { left: 1px; top: 1px; }
.ui-resizable-ne { top: 1px; right: 1px; }
.ui-resizable-sw { bottom: 1px; left: 1px; }
```

As you can see the div1 is **resizable**,draggable and has absolute width and height. Div2 has 100% width and height and has absolute position. Div3 has the parameters to be centered horizontally and vertically.

I have a [screenshot](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/5188/handles.jpg) of what i want to do. I want the white handles to be outside the div like shown in the screenshot. The second div must stay with position:absolute. There is also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3bnS/1/) that contains my current code.

Please help me move the handles outside of the div.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/U3bnS/4/

Comment: Use negative values (f. e. `right:-5px;`) to set the correct position. I've updated your example. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3bnS/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

But there is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jloureiro09/ukXap/).

I've change only your `css`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the handle's by more than you have in the `css` you've outlined. I've tidied it up a bit and you can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9jFv/1/)

```
.ui-resizable-handle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.ui-resizable-n, .ui-resizable-s {
    left:50%;
}
.ui-resizable-e, .ui-resizable-w {
    top:50%;    
}

.ui-resizable-se {
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
}
```